# Error in Running Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application, ready to be run in STS(Spring Tool Suite)

I followed [This][1]

[1]: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html link.

I'm getting a WhiteLabel Error :

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 29 11:46:52 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Is it because I'm running it on the Pivotal Server?

SHould I use Tomcat?

Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Please post your project structure

Comment: How do I post it here? as A picture?

Comment: Please post it as a Picture and Full exception stacktrace will do

Comment: I'm being unable to upload the image, due to a very slow Internet Connection. I'm posting the stacktrace here

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 29 12:08:25 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Project Structure : src/main/java/hello - (1)Application.java and (2)HelloController.java
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view - index.jsp

Comment: Any idea?? SHould I post any other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that your RequestMapping for the index page, and its corresponding method, both are in the same file as the main method.

Comment: Yes! The controller and the main methods both were in different files. I included both in the same file, and it worked. Thanks,